# Input and creation of an object

Tags: grails

Hello I just started Grails and I  created a simple domain class User with only 1 property: `String name`, I was wondering how should my view and controller look like if I want to get input a String from the browser and from this input to create new object of type User and save it to the database with `.save()` command ,thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve & http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty of good information available on the [Grails site](http://docs.grails.org/latest/).

If you want to see basic examples, then you should explore the grails command line.

Startup grails at the command line in your project folder, then at the prompt enter generate and hit the TAB key. Grails can walk you through what it can auto-generate, and this includes controllers and views. Good for educational reading.

```
grails> generate
```